# reading date field from csv file into dataframe

Tags: python, date, dataframe, pandas

I have a CSV file which contains a date in the format `2011,1,10,`

The format in my dataframe, which I am loading that date into, should be `2011-01-10`.

I am using the following code to load the date out of the file:

```
read_csv("test.csv", parse_date=[[0,2]])
```

How do I convert it to read in as 2011-01-10?

Answer (score 3):

You nearly had it! The correct syntax for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) is (`parse_dates`):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=[[0,1,2]])
Out[2]: 
        year_month_day
0  2011-01-10 00:00:00
```

*Where **test.csv** is:*

```
year,month,day
2011,1,10
```

Comment: Thanks hayden, It worked. How ever, I was having difficulties when I tried to add more comma separated data into the "test.csv" it was not reading the correct dates. Solution was provided in another thread here. add "header=None" or to add header and the columns are read properly.(I just noticed that there is a header on the sample "test.csv" above)

Comment: @user1908555 Sorry, perhaps I should have asked for the layout of your csv! Glad you fixed it :)